# Can I use "get" and "default" dynamically in rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Right now I'm using id's for the urls to my pages controller with a few exceptions like this:

`get '/contact' => 'pages#show', :defaults => { :id => '2' }`

Now there are more and more exceptions coming in, so I get tired of hardcoding them. Is there a way I can use the classical way and the pretty url way at the same time, so the old urls will still be working?

`www.example.com/**pages/2**`

and

`www.example.com/**contact**`

when `Page.find(2).slug == "contact"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this at the **end** of your routes file, if placed anywhere else in the file it will override everything:

```
get '/:page' => controller#action
```

And on that controller action:

```
def action
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      slug = request.path.split('/').last
      page = Page.find_by(slug: slug) if slug
      if page
        pages_controller = PagesController.new(request: request, response: response, params: { id: page.id })
        pages_controller.process('show').last
      else
        render status: 404 # or raise 404 error the way you do in your application
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can also redirect instead of rendering but that would change the URL which you don't want to. You can also find better ways to render the action but this way you can achieve what your are trying to do.

Comment: There are a lot of cons to adding a very permissive catch-all to your application like this though. Failing tests which would have for example caused a routing error will start getting plugged into this controller as well as it catching stuff like pesky bot requests. Think careful if you REALLY need it before adding it to your app.

Comment: It would also be better if you use a less permissive expression like `get '/:page', to: 'pages#show'` instead of a wildcard.